# Android Studio Passing list of views between activities?

Tags: android, list, android-studio, arraylist, view

Im a beginner in android studio and im trying to pass a list of views between activities, this is my declaration: `List<View> myList = new ArrayList<View>();`

But I dont think `putExtra()`can be used to pass a list of views (it works for list of strings though). This is what Ive tried:

`Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.javipasku.conditionreport.Main2Activity");
intent.putExtra("d", myList);
startActivity(intent);`

I get an error message saying the method putExtra cannot be resolved with this type of list.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: THere's no reason to ever do this.  Views depend on their context, they can't be displayed in another activity.  What you're trying to do is invalid.  Instead you should pass the data needed to create your views.

Comment: @gabesechan Ok thanks for the quick response, really appreciate it. What I want to do is store them somewhere so that when I return to my activity they do not reset, is there a simple way of doing this which you could possibly explain to me? Like I said I only just started using Android Studio and I havnt found any solution on this, thanks in advance

Comment: If the application isn't killed for resources this should happen automatically.  If the app is being killed for resources, you should implement onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState, saving enough data to be able to recreate the state in onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Why don't you write a class which extends application, and have a static variable in that class, this class will preserve value of any variable until application is terminated.

Comment: Alright I see what I am doing wrong thanks guys for the very fast answers. Never thought this site would actually be this useful, guess I was wrong.